# Add text to the start of a SOLR database value

Tags: sql, database, solr, field

I am using this code for my SOLR DIH:

```
<dataConfig>
    <dataSource name="app" driver="org.postgresql.Driver" url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/wikipedia" user="wikipedia" password="secret" />
    <dataSource name="data" driver="org.postgresql.Driver" url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/wikipedia" user="wikipedia" password="secret" />
    <document> 
        <entity dataSource="app-ds" name="item" query="SELECT id, title, description, date, link, location_id, source_id, company_id from item"> 
            <field column="id" name="id" /> 
            <field column="title" name="title" /> 
            <field column="description" name="description" />   
            <field column="date" name="date" /> 
            <field column="link" name="link" />
        <entity dataSource="app-ds" name="location" query="SELECT name, coordinate from location where location_id=${item.location_id}"> 
            <field column="name" name="location_name" /> 
            <field column="coordinate" name="location_coordinates" /> 
                        </entity> 
        <entity dataSource="app-ds" name="source" query="SELECT name from source where source_id=${item.source_id}"> 
                <field column="name" name="source_name" /> 
                        </entity> 
                   <entity dataSource="app-ds" name="company" query="SELECT name from company where company_id=${item.company_id}"> 
                <field column="name" name="company_name" /> 
                </entity> 
        </entity> 
    </document> 
</dataConfig>
```

Since I am merging two databases I want to have a uniqueID for each entry within SOLR. In my case the best way of doing this is to have app**ID** for the first databases ID's and data**ID** for the second databases ID's.

Using my code above, how do I add the word "app" to the front of the ID that is stored in the SOLR ID field so that my database ID=123 and the Solr ID = app123

EDIT: As I guess it might be something like this (but I am not good with SQL)

```
query="SELECT app_(id)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to modify the SQL Query as -

> SELECT 'TABLE1' || ID AS PRIMARY_ID ........

PRIMARY_ID can be now configured as unique ID in solr.

```
<field column="primary_id" name="primary_id" />
```

Even if you are performing incremental updates using Delta imports, the SQL ID updated would still generate the Same Solr ID with the above query and would be updated. So be sure to use the above in the Delta queries as well.

Comment: I need the ID in the SQLdatabase to collerate with the ID in the SOLR database. By putting a known value at the start of the SOLR value I will know that the SOLR ID is "app"+"SQLID". Although your answer is good, I would have no record of the SOLRID on the SQL side of things.

Comment: You dont need any record of Solr ID on the SQL Side. Even if you are performing incremental updates using Delta imports, the SQL ID updated would still generate the Same Solr ID with the above query and would be updated.

Comment: If database A has an item with ID=123 and database B also has an item with ID = 123 and I put them both into SOLR, what happens then, wont there be two records with the same ID?

Comment: but wouldn't you apply the db1 and db2 identifier to both the ids when you index that data so that the id is still unique ?

Comment: Yes, but that is what I dont know how to do, should I have an SQL field which has the ID plus the identifier as well as a field which is just the ID?

Comment: yes. You can still hold both Primary Id and ID as fields in Solr. The SQL ID field can be used for Querying. If your application is able to retrieve ID from Solr Primary Id field you may even not need the SQL ID field in Solr.